# Best way to export and import products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, importexport

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4 and want to know what is the best way to export and import products from one Magento installation to another.

I read a lot of things but none of them worked for me. My current Magento store has multiple websites, configurable products etc. When I try the simple export (`System > Import/Export > Export`) it does not work because the new store (where I am importing the products) does not have multiple websites.

When I try to use the profile export (`System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profile`) it does not work because the configurable products can't find the attributes set on the new store.

Is there a good way to "transfer" products from one installation to another?

Comment: you need to create all custom option as well as attribute option on new store

Comment: Thank you for your comment...I tried to do that and many other things and nothing worked...so I ended up just creating the products manually...

Comment: Can you share Skype id i will send you script foe import product using csv. But also you need to create attribute.